# PHP multiple if else shorthand error

Tags: php

```
$array['something'] ? $a ?$b ? $c : '';
```

In 3 var there's one have value, and assign it to the array, but It doesn't work.

Comment: What does `"but It doesn't work"` mean...? What is the expected output? What are the errors? More information usually helps champ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

`$array['something'] = !empty($a) ? $a : (!empty($b) ? $b : (!empty($c) ? $c : ""));`

Only one of `$a`, `$b` or `$c` has a value and assign only that value

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$array['something'] = (($a) ? $a : (($b) ? $b : (($c) ? $c : '')));
```

Comment: A sentence or two by way of explanation goes a long way toward turning an answer that is simply correct into a great one that will receive up-votes and future views.